# How to document an event handler in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
function myClass(q) {
  this.someFunction = function(e) {
      console.log("Click event");
  };

  jQuery(q).click(this.someFunction);
}
```

Is there a way to indicate to JSDoc that someFunction is not just a function that should be invoked directly but rather is an event handler ?

I see the @event tag but if I understand correctly this is more to document a function in my class that I consider to be an event (something the client code would register too and that my class will fire when needed) and not an event handler function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>No, there is no way to document an event handler.</strike>

So the best way is to document it as a normal function maybe writing in its description in bold text or upper case that is an "EVENT HANDLER".

You probably already now this, but just in case: you can write it in bold by simply wrapping the text into html tags `<strong></strong>`.

This answer is now deprecated but it does not let me delete it.

Comment: This answer should be removed.

Comment: @Chris Marisic: I agree, but it does not let me delete it because it's the accepted answer.

Comment: You can edit it, using strikethroughs to deprecate your old answer, and then either giving the correct answer or directing users to someone else's correct answer.

Answer (score 28):

The keyword is [@listens](https://jsdoc.app/tags-listens.html)

Usage example:

```
/**
 * Outputs the event that happened
 *
 * @param {MyEvent} e - The observable event.
 * @listens MyEvent
 */
function myEventLogger(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

The corollary is the [@fires](https://jsdoc.app/tags-fires.html) keyword for raising the event.

Comment: `@listens` is now an [documented feature of JSDoc 3](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-listens.html).

Comment: I came across this post looking for a way to document "on" events such as socket.io's `io.on('connection', function(socket) { // do things } );` and jQuery's `$(document).on('click', '.my_class', function() { // do things } );`.  It *seems* a link to the relevant jsdoc comments is not included in the generated documentation when using something like `@listens connection`?  Perhaps because there is no way to define a corollary `@fires` event - eg the socket.io code that creates the `connection` event?  Same for the jQuery example - how would you define a `@fires` event for an on click handler?